# PHP strtolower ignoring the first character

Tags: php, character

I am looking for a way in which each word from the 2nd letter to write everything small. The first letter should be ignored. Does anyone have an idea?

```
<?php
    $string = "This is a GREAT String";
    echo " . strtolowerbutnotthefirst($string) . "; // This is a Great String
?>
```

Comment: Do you really want to ignore the first one? Or should this one be uppercase? If so: http://php.net/ucfirst

Comment: Yes, i want to ignore the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write your own function to do this. Use something like the following:

```
<?php

function lcwords_ignore_first(&$word, $key)
{
    $word = $word[0] . strtolower(substr($word, 1));
}

$string = "This is a GREAT String";
$words = explode(" ", $string);
array_walk($words, 'lcwords_ignore_first');
echo implode(" ", $words); // Output: This is a Great String
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do something as to make **each word from the 2nd Letters to write everything small**

```
$string = "This is a GREAT String";

ucwords(strtolower($string));
```